# Noticeable inconsistency in font sizes for subheaders

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Here is a noticeable inconsistency in font sizes for subheaders on the "all revisions" and "single revision" pages:

https://giphy.com/gifs/stack-overflow-Xbfu0zueDYkszketuG/fullscreen

Compare

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55991633/revisions  ("all revisions" page)
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55991633/2 ("single revision" page)

Details

"all revisions" page:
[image]

"single revision" page:
[image]

Comment: someone has too much free time... but to be fair, such things bug me too :)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth not really... it's just screamingly noticeable to a perfectionist's eye - I couldn't pass by.

Comment: Don't even get me started on the slight color variations. The two headers you are showing are two different blues too.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ It appears to me that one of the links is visited, and the other is not. I could be wrong though.

Comment: All Revisions is gray and bold, whereas Single Revision is blue and apparently non-bold.